# iOS GCM GCMPubSub Unsubscription Error 7 - Unknown Error

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

For GCM topic messaging, whilst trying to unsubscribe from a topic I'm getting the following in my log (see code below)

```
Failed to unsubscribe from topic /topics/testTopicName: Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 7.)"
```

Now, I'm able to subscribe to the topic with the same registration token, as well as receiving topical messages for this topic, yet I'm not able to unsubscribe from it. I'm getting this every time when trying to unsubscribe. According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client), "7" is an "unknown error" - great...

I've observed the same behaviour for all the topics I've created so far.

```
+ (void)unsubscribeFromGCMTopic:(NSString*)topicName
{
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to unsubscribe from the
// topic
if (app.registrationToken && app.connectedToGCM)
{
    NSString* topic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", TOPIC_PREFIX, topicName];

    [[GCMPubSub sharedInstance] unsubscribeWithToken:app.registrationToken
                                               topic:topic
                                             options:nil
                                             handler:^void(NSError *error)
                                             {
                                                 if (error)
                                                 {
                                                     NSLog(@"Failed to unsubscribe from topic %@: %@", topic, error);                                                        
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     // Unsubscribe successfully
                                                     NSLog(@"Successfully unsubscribe from topic %@", topic);
                                                 }
                                             }];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot GCM unsubscribe from %@. Token %@. GCM connection status %d", topicName, app.registrationToken, app.connectedToGCM);
}
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error code 7 usually means that the response from the server was invalid. Are you still able to send downstream messages to the topic even after unsubscribing (not withstanding the fact that the code returned unsuccessful subscribe)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still able to send downstream messages for the (what should be unsubscribed) topic

Comment: Umm this seems weird, it's working fine for me. You  might want to do a delayed retry on failure. Not sure why it's happening for all your topics. Did you try deleting the app and getting a new gcmToken and trying with it?

Answer (score 0):

check in app delegate if using sandbox or production kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]

for production:

```
 //RECEBE DADOS CERTIFICADOS_APNS_TOKENS
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
    deviceToken: NSData ) {
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self

        print("\nDEVICE: \(deviceToken)\n")


        //PARA TESTAR NOTIFICACAO COLOCAR SANDBOX COMO TRUE e para PRODUCAO COLOCAR COMO FALSE
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:false]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)

}
```

for test using true:

```
 //RECEBE DADOS CERTIFICADOS_APNS_TOKENS
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
    deviceToken: NSData ) {
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self

        print("\nDEVICE: \(deviceToken)\n")


        //PARA TESTAR NOTIFICACAO COLOCAR SANDBOX COMO TRUE e para PRODUCAO COLOCAR COMO FALSE
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)

}
```